# Moment js time stamp

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I am using `moment.js` to parse my date time and I am getting totally confused.

If I do `moment().toDate()` I get:

```
Fri Aug 21 2020 21:52:48 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)
```

which is exactly correct. I am showing this so that you know that `moment` is not pulling incorrect local time for me.

I have a time which looks like this that I pulling from a database:

```
2020-08-21T21:49:58.000Z
```

As you can see this is the same day as above but a slightly different time like 3 minutes ago.

If I do:

```
moment("2020-08-21T21:49:58.000Z").calendar()
```

it returns :

> "Today at 5:49 PM"

which is incorrect.

However, if remove `0Z` from the end of the time stamp and do this:

```
moment("2020-08-21T21:49:58.00").calendar()
```

I get

> "Today at 9:49 PM"

which is correct.

I am guessing by looking at the format moment decides it is a UTC time and subtract 4 hours from it.

Therefore, I thought I would convert it back to utc() but when I do:

`moment("2020-08-21T21:49:58.000Z").utc().calendar(`)

I get:

> "Yesterday at 9:49 PM"

which decreases it by 24 hours and I am not sure why.

Is there a function that I can use to prevent it from assuming that the time is in UTC format?

**Edit 1:**

If I do `moment().toDate()` I get:

> Sun Aug 23 2020 20:53:28 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)

which is correct.

When I try to use the time stamp from today:

```
moment("2020-08-23T20:52:38.000Z").utc().calendar()
```

I am getting:

> "Yesterday at 8:52 PM"

Comment: You want to show yesterday time at today's time with `.calender()` ? Can you please add more details to what you want in the final results - Thanks

Comment: Yes. If the date was yesterday, it should say yesterday 9:49 PM. However, since in my case above the date is clearly today, it should say today 9:49 PM

Comment: Since this is time relative, you should note the time you runs these commands

Comment: @dongnhan you are right. The format stops working after around 7-8 pm of my local time where it starts saying yesterday instead of today but works perfectly fine when it morning and afternoon of my local time

Comment: @goxarad784 Are you still looking for a solution on this ?

Comment: Yes. I am using `moment(myTimeStamp).utc().calendar()` and it is working right now. As soon as it is evening time it stops working and it suddenly starts saying yesterday instead of today. I am completely baffled.

Comment: Do you really want to use `.calender` like its a must for you ?

Comment: Whats the current date where you are at the present ?

Comment: I am debating if I really need it. Having said that I think I do have a solution. Using `utc()` messes somthing up and I do not understand what. My time stamp says 0Z at the end which means its UTC 0 but I am at UTC -4.  I can change the database time and decrease it by 4 hours before insertion or I can remove just the 0Z from the time stamp by using `moment("2020-08-23T20:52:38").format('YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss')`

Comment: However, it looks like I cannot do moment().format().calendar()

Comment: @goxarad784 No! you cannot do `moment().format().calendar()` - Let me do some work for you and help you out. Wait!

Comment: If the times stored in your database end with `Z`, they are UTC times. Unless you have reason to believe they have been _stored_ incorrectly, you shouldn't be trying to interpret them as referring to Eastern Daylight Time. Also, if they _are_ stored incorrectly, your best bet is to fix that problem at source and clean any existing live data, rather than create workarounds for _formatting_ it.

Comment: @goxarad784 *I can change the database time and decrease it by 4 hours before insertion or I can remove just the 0Z* => thats a hack but not an efficient solution. Yes its possible that way!

Comment: The server I am hosting my app is at a different location then the place which will be using it. I wanted the timestamp to be created at the time of the client and not the server. So in my MSSQL database I do : `dateadd(hour,-4,GETUTCDATE())`.  So I am actually storing the timestamp as eastern daylight. It's just that I think javascript adds 0Z at the end by default which makes moment think that it is a UTC time zone

Comment: By best best if I want to use the `calendar()` is to figure out a way to achieve this `moment().format().calendar()` which I guess I can do using a function to return the formatted date but I am just looking for a better way to do that if it is out there.

Comment: try this and let me know => `let date = moment('2020-08-23T20:52:38.000Z').utcOffset('+04:00').calendar()` which this gives you!

Comment: @goxarad784 Did my solution worked for you ?? Let me know

Answer (score 0):

You could try to enable your moment object to local time mode:

```
moment("2020-08-21T21:49:58.000Z").local().calendar()
```

Comment: What is your time zone? I guess your time zone is -4 utc. If it is right then all the behaviour of the moment is correct. The "Z" in the timestamp stands for Zero, which means that timestamp is at utc 0 and that's why you get -4 hours when your format since your time zone is 4 hours latter than the 0 utc.